# MS SQL Server with encrypted password

Tags: sql-server, encryption

I am trying to create a table in SQL Server

```
create table admin (name varchar(40), pass varchar(40))
```

The problem is I don't want `password` to be visible I mean it should be shown like  **** as usual in log in systems.

Waiting to hear from you soon.

Comment: You should store you password hashed, in this case even if you see the hash it will not be much use, since you can't find out string from it's hash

Comment: so how can I make a hashed password in ms sql server please help? As in PHP we hash password like md5($passsword).

Comment: use BCrypt https://bcrypt.codeplex.com/